# Not recognised as "Arff data files file"

Tags: csv, weka, arff

I had .txt file and I opened it and saved it as *.csv* file.

Now I try to open it in weka and I got this type of error:
 `Null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weka uses **ARFF** as the **standard data file format**.

Since you haven't given an example of your newly created **CSV** I recomend you reading 
this about **CSV** files in Weka. http://weka.wikispaces.com/Can+I+use+CSV+files%3F

My opinion is that you should **format your data as in the ARFF format**, and you won't have any problem.

Here is a small **example**:

```
@relation ball

@attribute color {white, orange, brown}
@attribute diameter real
@attribute forma {circle, oval}
@attribute weight real
@attribute type {fotbal, pingpong, basket}

@data
white,10,circle,1000,fotbal
white,9,circle,800,fotbal
orange,1,circle,10,pingpong
white,1,circle,10,pingpong
brown,15,circle,1300,basket
brown,16,circle,1400,basket
white,9,circle,901,fotbal
white,10,circle,850,fotbal
orange,1,circle,8,pingpong
white,1,circle,9,pingpong
brown,16,circle,1350,basket
brown,16,circle,1401,basket
```